# Angular Material Theming not changing with overlaycontainer

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm trying to add a dark theme to my app :

So I have 2 themes light and dark like this :

```
$gok-app-accent: mat-palette($mat-deep-purple);
$gok-app-warn: mat-palette($mat-amber);
$gok-app-dark-theme: mat-dark-theme(
  (
    color: (
      accent: $gok-app-accent,
      primary: $gok-app-primary,
      warn: $gok-app-warn,
    ),
  )
);
```

I added 2 classes to my styles.scss :

```
.light-theme {
  @include angular-material-theme($gok-app-light-theme);
  @include all-components-theme($gok-app-light-theme);
}

.dark-theme {
  @include angular-material-theme($gok-app-dark-theme);
  @include all-components-theme($gok-app-dark-theme);
}
```

And I wanted to test if my classes are working but this code doesn't work!

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.overlayContainer.getContainerElement().classList.add("dark-theme");
  }
```

Btw, my mixins are working, when I put dark theme "includes" it works

Do you guys have any ideas ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally succeed to change theme with an other approach:

```
  @HostBinding("class") componentCssClass: string;

    ...
  ngOnInit() {
     this.componentCssClass = "dark-theme";
  }
```